# Convert to time spent

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that contains time spent like this format xxHyyM

It'll contain data like:

```
1H1M
2H8M
```

I need to convert it into total spent. If it's 1H30M it will show 1.5

I try within substring and dividing by 60 but I get always error.

Comment: Please provide other examples, particularly with more digits.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the letters with symbols so you can convert to a time.  SQL Server converts `'1:1:00'` correctly.

Then count the number of seconds and divide by 3600:

```
datediff(second, 0, convert(time, replace(replace(<col>, 'H', ':'), 'M', ':00'))) / (60 * 60.0)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2aa6262b95f8f91add18dae30de0667a) is a db<>fiddle.

If you need to handle other formats, use `case`:

```
(case when time_spent like '%H%M'
      then datediff(second, 0, convert(time, replace(replace(time_spent, 'H', ':'), 'M', ':00'))) / (60 * 60.0)
      when time_spent like '%H'
      then try_convert(int, replace(time_spent, 'H', ''))
      when time_spent like '%M'
      then try_convert(int, replace(time_spent, 'M', '')) / 60.0
 end)
```

Comment: I try it and it seems good only for one data when time_spent=1M it displays wrong result. I'm expected to have 0,016667 but I get 1.00000

Comment: @Powerbi . . . This works for all the examples mentioned in your question.

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly. But there is two small exceptions: when for example there is only M 3M, 8M or only H for example 8H, 9H..etc

Comment: Awesome! Top du top.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I suggest fixing the design here, but you could do something like this. Note this **assumes** there will always be a `'H'` and `'M'` in your string, based on the *two* examples we have:

```sql
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(int,LEFT(V.YourColumn,CHARINDEX('H',V.YourColumn)-1)) + 
       (TRY_CONVERT(decimal(2,0),REPLACE(STUFF(V.YourColumn,1,CHARINDEX('H',V.YourColumn),''),'M','')) / 60)
FROM (VALUES('1H1M'),
            ('2H8M'),
            ('1H30M'))V(YourColumn)
```

This returns, 1.016~, 2.13~ and 1.5 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

do you have try :

```
SELECT cast(cast('01.30:00' as datetime) as float) * 24
```